# django rest-auth login token use approach

Tags: django, rest

I am using django rest-auth for handling user registration and login. whenever I try to login, it gives me token. so my question is now how to make use of that token to log in user to the home page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryGbd.png)

what I want is to make use of that token to login the user in to home page.
thank you

Comment: You need to pass the token in the header. Go to header tab > in key column -> Authorization, Value column -> Token <your token>, just google it :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the token along with every request (in the request headers) to show that the user is logged.

In Postman, go to headers and add the following under Authorization (make sure it's checked too).

Token  (without the brackets).

[image]